# NULL values are not inserted into sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a CSV file with three columns of "movieId", "imdbId", "tmdbId". The column "tmdbId" contains multiple empty rows.(movieId is a froeign key referring to a primary key in another table)

When I read this data frame into R, the empty rows are treated as NA values. If I import this CSV file into mysql DB using the following command, the rows with NA values don’t get inserted in the table, even though I allow NULL values. I should also mention that, I do not get any errors.

Beside the following command, I also tried importing the dataset using MySQL workbench, but it did not work.

any suggestion?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'links.csv' INTO TABLE links
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(movieId, imdbId, tmdbId);
```

I know NULL and NA values are not the same, but I do not understand why R treats empty rows as NA. I tried to replace NA with NULL, but R does not support this operation.

The TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE links ( 
    movieId int NOT NULL, 
    imdbId int DEFAULT NULL, 
    tmdbId int DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY movieId (movieId), 
    CONSTRAINT links_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES movieId_title (movieId) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The CSV file looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAtwI.png)

Here is an example of an empty row for the third column:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS2Ms.png)

Comment: Would be useful to see your schema for this table. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE links;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: I have remove the tag oracle.

Comment: In the question please, using the EDIT link. Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: And add an example of links.csv file content (5-6 rows). As formatted text.

Comment: Use `set foreign_key_checks = 0;`, before inserting. It should insert those rows without a value. The only issue is it will default to 0 since it is an int column and is converting from a string.  InnoDB does not allow inserting a row that violates the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alec suggested, you can do `set foreign_key_checks = 0`. Then, you can replace zeros with NULL using the following command:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col_name= NULL 
WHERE  col_name  = 0;
```